# Laravel 5 hash changes every time with Ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel, hash, laravel-5, bcrypt

the following is the modal which is invoked on button click

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Compose New Task</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body db">
                                    <div class="form-group db">
                                    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Current Password </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input type="password" id="current_password" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">New Password </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input type="password" id="new_password" class="form-control">
                                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="csrftoken">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="error" id="message"></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="updatePassword">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Relevant line in the above code is number 11

```
$("#updatePassword").click(function () {

var current_password = document.getElementById('current_password').value;
var new_password = document.getElementById('new_password').value;
var token = document.getElementById('csrftoken').value;

$.post('/modalupdatePassword', {'current_password': current_password, 'new_password': new_password, '_token': token}, function (data) {

    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(parsed);

    $('#message').append(parsed);

});
});
```

and this is my modalPasswordUpdate function

```
public function modalUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $current_password = bcrypt($request->current_password);
    $updateRequest = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('password', $current_password)
    ->first();

    echo json_encode($current_password);

}
```

Now every time I send the request I am getting different hash

following is my updated code

```
Route::get('check', function()
{
echo $password = Hash::make('secret');
});
```

this also returns new password everytime

Comment: Is your session working properly?

Comment: yes I am able to login on the website with correct password and navigate to different pages without dropping the session

Answer (score 1):

You are sending your request via post. Laravel documentation states, that the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware will look for `X-CSRF-TOKEN` request headers during post requests, so do try the following.

Add the token to a meta tag in the head of your document.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Now add the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` as a header to the global ajax settings like so

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Now all AJAX requests will automatically include the CSRF token.

You can read more about this on the Laravel docs right [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing).

Comment: you are still not sending your csrf-token correctly.